# binding images in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I have a listbox that is populated from a datatable. I want each item to have a specific image on listbox, but I want to set the image depending of an id that each item has.
for example , I have :

**Products**

Orange

Apple

**ID**

1

2

and the images are named: **Item.1.png** ,  **Item.2.png**

So, in my listbox,where I have apple, I will have next to it the image named: Item.2.png.

My problem is that I don't know how could I do a conditional binding . I don't want to have on my template hundreds of lines that are doing this for each item. I need to do this using a condition, like : if(product.id==1), Image.Source=Item.1.png.
Is there any way to do this in wpf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need an `IdToImageConverter` that will decides which `Image` should be shown dependant on the value of the `Id` property. Something like this should do the trick:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class IdToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(int) || targetType != typeof(ImageSource)) return false;
        int id = (int)value;
        if (id < 0) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        string imageName = string.Empty;
        switch (id)
        {
            case 1: imageName = "Item.1.png"; break;
            case 2: imageName = "Item.2.png"; break;
        }
        if (imageName.IsEmpty()) return null;
        return string.Format("/AppName;component/ImageFolderName/{0}", imageName);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
```

You could then use it in your `ListBox.ItemTemplate` something like this:

```
<YourConvertersXmlNamespacePrefix:IdToImageConverter x:Key="IdToImageConverter" />
...
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource 
IdToImageConverter}}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question, every object in the listbox has an ID property, where you want the image to be item.*ID*.png.

You could use a converter in your binding to do this. So in your listbox template, you can have something like:

```
// ... Listbox template
<Image Source={Binding pathToItemID, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}/>
// ... Remaining ListBox template
```

You will need to add the converter to the UserControl's resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <xmlnsPointingToConverter:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then add a MyConverter class which implements [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("item.{0}.png", value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```